# Geographic coordinates to screen coordinates algorithm

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, geo

I'm developing a cross platform mobile application that stores positions as geographic coordinates into a db, each of these points represent the top left corner of a graphical object.

This application contains a map control (radmap from telerik), that supports geographic coordinates, so, you just add the rectangle and it draws it correctly.

Due to licensing problem I cannot use the map control in the android version (google doesn't let us use the map control for business applications - https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_commercial, for ios I still didn't check this out), so I will use an image to be used as background.

I've got the top left corner and bottom right geographic coordinates of the "map/image" and I've got to draw the graphical objects inside the area defined by the corners.

Could anyone help me to discover how to convert the geographic coordinates to screen coordinates.

Data example (X,Y):

```
        GEO
```

Top left corner:

-0,00939846 -0,00504255

Bottom right corner:

0,009398461 -0,01281023

Points to draw:

-0.00464558,-0.00799298

-0.0046509,-0.00845432

-0.00386774,-0.00860988

-0.00344932,-0.00860452

```
        SCREEN
```

Top left corner:

0 0

Bottom right corner:

? ?

Points to draw

? ?

Screen size

1024 * 768

Thanks for the help,

Luis Pinho

Comment: You've tagged Monodroid and Monotouch. Is this actually a Xamarin application?

Comment: Yes it is, I'm using Xamarin Trial version (for now) and plan to buy a business license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm most fluent in `iOS` so that's what my answers in. I tried to make as many variables as possible so that you could either manually/programmatically override them without changing too much of the other code.

```
- (CGPoint)convertGeoPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView*)view {
    CGPoint geoTopLeft = CGPointMake(-0.00939846, -0.00504255);
    CGPoint geoBottomRight = CGPointMake(0.009398461, -0.01281023);
    CGFloat geoWidth = geoBottomRight.x - geoTopLeft.x;
    CGFloat geoHeight = geoBottomRight.y - geoTopLeft.y;

    // This is the block you would change to suit your needs
    CGPoint viewTopLeft = CGPointMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y);
    CGFloat viewWidth = view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat viewHeight = view.frame.size.height;

    return CGPointMake(viewTopLeft.x + (point.x-geoTopLeft.x)*viewWidth/geoWidth, viewTopLeft.y + (point.y-geoTopLeft.y)*viewHeight/geoHeight);
}
```

The basic idea is that you need to convert the point into the new coordinate system.  To do this, you need to divide by the appropriate geographic dimension and multiply by the appropriate view dimension.

Comment: Hi Sam, I'm running your code in excel (I don't have any osx available at this moment - left it in the office - to run it on xCode). And according to my simulations the results seems to be promising, at least the test that I've got all run correctly using this algorithm. Thanks you very much!!!

Comment: Glad to help!  Let me know if it ends up not working as you expected.